# Set the background color of a Snackbar in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, background-color, material-ui

I am using a `Snackbar` component from Material UI. At the moment the `Snackbar` appears in black. Do you know how I can change the color? Setting background-color only changes the color of the whole div in which the `Snackbar` is presented. It does not change the color of the `Snackbar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the `bodyStyle` property:

```
<Snackbar bodyStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'teal', color: 'coral' }} />
```

You can find more info about how you customize the snackbars in the [documentation](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/snackbar)

Comment: As of 3/1/19  Material UI V3.9.2 this is no longer working. The example below by Emi worked fine for me.

Answer (score 42):

With Material UI v1 you should override the root CSS class from the SnackbarContent component with the prop **ContentProps**.

Here is an example:

```js
const styles = {
  root: {
    background: 'red'
  }
};

class MySnackbar extends Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <Snackbar
        ContentProps={{
          classes: {
            root: classes.root
          }
        }}
        message={<span>Some message</span>}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(MySnackbar);
```

If someone does not want to pass style as props, we can also write a class in a CSS file and assign it to the ContentProps, like this:

```
ContentProps={{
  classes: {
    root: 'errorClass'
  }
}}
```

and in index.css file:

```
.errorClass { color: 'red' }
```

Comment: My journey to find out how to change the  material-ui snackbar component's color is finally over. Thanks, emi!

Answer (score 16):

With the current material-ui version (4.3.0) there is a even simpler approach than the **ContentProps** way. Instead of the `message` attribute you can use a `SnackbarContent` as child and simply call `style={}` on it

```
<Snackbar
  open={this.state.showSnackbar}
  autoHideDuration={3000}
  onClose={() => {this.setState({showSnackbar: false})}}
>
  <SnackbarContent style={{
      backgroundColor:'teal',
    }}
    message={<span id="client-snackbar">Hello World</span>}
  />
</Snackbar>
```

Answer (score 7):

The root component of the `Snackbar` only concerns about positioning itself correctly, if you want to change the appearance of the physical `Snackbar`, you need to target the `SnackbarContent` via `ContentProps` prop. In v5, you can use the [`sx`](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content) to do that easily:

```
<Snackbar
  ContentProps={{
    sx: {
      background: "red"
    }
  }}
```

Another way is to create a [custom variant](https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/#adding-new-component-variants) for your `Snackbar`:

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiSnackbar: {
      variants: [
        {
          props: { variant: "trouble" },
          style: {
            "& .MuiSnackbarContent-root": {
              background: "orange"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          props: { variant: "bigTrouble" },
          style: {
            "& .MuiSnackbarContent-root": {
              background: "red"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```
<Snackbar variant="bigTrouble"
```

To use with typescript, you also need to update the prop type of `Snackbar`:

```
declare module "@mui/material/Snackbar" {
  interface SnackbarProps {
    variant: "trouble" | "bigTrouble";
  }
}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 1):

With Material UI v5 the optimal option to customize Snackbar (background, text color or any other styles) is to use sx prop and specific classNames for variants:

```
<Snackbar
  sx={{
    '& .SnackbarItem-variantSuccess': {
      backgroundColor: colors.primary, //your custom color here
    },
    '& .SnackbarItem-variantError': {
      backgroundColor: colors.alert, //your custom color here
    },
    '& .SnackbarItem-variantWarning': {
      backgroundColor: colors.attention, //your custom color here
    },
    '& .SnackbarItem-variantInfo': {
      backgroundColor: colors.secondary, //your custom color here
    },
  }}
  autoHideDuration={10000}
  //...other props here>
</Snackbar>
```

The same approach can be applied to notistack library to customize their snackbar.